# Unable to route from on page component to another page

Tags: angular

I am new in angular 2,I am using ng2-admin template which is in angular 2.0.0 version.
I want to route my pages from component like if user is successfully logged in then route to dashboard page.Currently i am using "route.navigate(['dashboard'])"
But after call to function it gives me error like undefined routes.
Following is the component side code:
[image]

my module.ts file is
[image]

my login routing component is as :
[image]

and main routing component is as :
[image]

please help me out,
Thanks

Comment: Post the routing component also, error is pointing out that that route is missing.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to `import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';` and then you will have to do declare your routes as below in your `app.ts` or `main.ts`:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'dashboard',  component: DashboardComponent },
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
```

Then you can use the `routes` in your corresponding component like below:

```
this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
```

Adding a new `function`:

```
gotoDashBoard() {
    console.log("coming");
    console.log(this);
    this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
}
```

And `call` this in your `response => {this.gotoCrises()}`.

Comment: If he has declared them in the routing component you don't need to declare them again in the app.module

Comment: @RohitDeshmukh: Did it help?

Comment: No sir,Sorry to say but again same error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'routes' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'routes' of undefined"

Comment: I am guessing this could be the reason of arrow functions here =>, can you change that to normal function and see if you can get the "this" value

Comment: @RohitDeshmukh: put a console.log(this) and see what it is... i am guessing its not what is expected.

Comment: No it is not working,Is there any other way there are 3 route components in ng-admin template 1) app.route.ts  2)pages.route.ts 3)our newpage.route.ts.

Comment: @RohitDeshmukh: Check my updated post, try it out and let me know

Comment: It prints console log  "coming" Login
form
:
FormGroup
http
:
Http
passphrase
:
FormControl
router
:
Router,
submitted
:
true  following same routes error

Comment: Does it throw the same error for this again "this.router.navigate(['/dashboard'])"